# Error: could not find function `fread` in R

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to read the file given in the question. But for unknown reasons, Rstudio is not able to detect the function `fread`. It showed the message:

> Error: could not find function `fread`

I have done following things to solve the issue:

1. installing package "data.table"
2. update java
3. install cygwin and gfortran (as suggested in a post on stackoverflow)

Please help me through it.

Comment: Did you load the package: `library(data.table)`?

Comment: did you load the library? `require(data.table)`

Comment: @RHertel most of the time its better to use `library` than `require` ([source](http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/))